# How to put and use two different values in buffer in C?

Tags: c, robotics

The following is part of a C code to make a robot move in its simulator.

```
while (1)
{
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 100 100\n");    //motor left and right moves with speed 100 each.
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket (simulator)
        int lme, rme;                  //lme and rme are right and left motor encoder values, the other value I need to send to buffer.
        sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");      //sensor command to find ME values
        sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);       //sending the actual ME values, that need to be sent to a(nother?) buffer.
        printf(buf, "lme , rme");      //the values of MEncoders.
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                //clear the buffer, set buffer value to 0
    read(sock, buf, 80);               //read from socket to get results.        
}
```

This does not work, as although the robot moves with speed 100, the terminal just shows S MELR and no motor encoder values, but it shows the value when the M LR command is removed so I think it has something to do with the MELR values not being sent to the buffer. How can this be improved or how can I set a new buffer for the MELR values?

Comment: What's the intent of `printf(buf, "lme , rme");`? Looks very wrong.

Comment: It will show the value of the motor encoder in terminal. ("Motor encoders count the number of revolutions made by each motor. Your software can read back these counts and use it to compensate for the difference between the voltage you commanded and the speed you actually achieved. To drive in a straight line then typically requires a constant series of changes to the motor voltages to correct for deviations from what you wished the motor to do.")

Comment: As I can understand the task should be: 1. send a motion command to simulator via socket, 2. send a "get encoder values" command to simulator via socket, 3. read response from socket, 4. parse response extracting encoders values, 5. print encoder values. Is that correct? If answer is "yes" then, how many times do you send commands in your code? I see only 1. And I can not see that you read response with encoders values for parsing.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask... Do you actually know what `sprintf` and `sscanf` do? I'm just asking, because you try to read integers from string you just created yourself, and which does not contain any...

Answer (score 2):

These lines are clearly wrong:

```
sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");      //sensor command to find ME values
sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);
```

Above you first set that string to `buf`, then try to parse two integers out of it, when it clearly does not have them.

It's hard to say for sure, but it looks like you need to `write` after that `sprintf` above, then move that `read` after that to actually get the response, before `sscanf`.

---

Then this printf is also nonsense: `printf(buf, "lme , rme");`

Do you perhaps mean something like this: `printf("Got lme %i, rme %i\n", lme, rme);`

Or what is the purpose of that `printf`? It's not really clear from the comment...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there are some things missing / wrong. I am annotating your code here:

```
while (1)
{
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 100 100\n");    //motor left and right moves with speed 100 each.
```

`buf` now contains the string "M LR 100 100\n"

```
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket (simulator)
```

Command is written to `sock`

```
        int lme, rme;                  //lme and rme are right and left motor encoder values, the other value I need to send to buffer.

        sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");      //sensor command to find ME values
```

A new command is written to `buf`

```
        sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);       //sending the actual ME values, that need to be sent to a(nother?) buffer.
```

Trying to read from `buf` - but it contains `"S MELR\n"`...

> --> probably want another `write(sock, buf, strlen(buf)); read(sock,buf,80);` here

```
    printf(buf, "lme , rme");      //the values of MEncoders.
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                //clear the buffer, set buffer value to 0
```

Writing a string to `buf`, and immediately clearing it again?

```
    read(sock, buf, 80);               //read from socket to get results.        
}
```

Maybe I misunderstand how `buf` operates, but it seems to be a string buffer - as evidenced by the use of at least one `write(sock...` operation.

If you address the points above you may get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to read buf once more? What do you want to do with lme and rme?

```
while (1)
{
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 100 100\n");    //motor left and right moves with speed 100 each.
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket (simulator)
        int lme, rme;                  //lme and rme are right and left motor encoder values, the other value I need to send to buffer.
        sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");      //sensor command to find ME values
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket 
    read(sock, buf, 80);               //read from socket to get results.    
        sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);       //sending the actual ME values, that need to be sent to a(nother?) buffer.
        // ???? printf(buf, "lme , rme");      //the values of MEncoders.
    memset(buf, 0, 80);                //clear the buffer, set buffer value to 0
    read(sock, buf, 80);  //???        //read from socket to get results.        
}
```

How you can “*compensate for the difference between the voltage you commanded and the speed you actually achieved*”??. I don’t have any idea about robots… but you can try : ?

```
int lme=100, rme=100;     //lme and rme are right and left motor encoder values, the other value I need to send to buffer.             
while (1)
{
    sprintf(buf, "M LR %i %i\n", lme, rme);    //motor left and right moves with speed 100 each.
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket (simulator)
        sprintf(buf, "S MELR\n");      //sensor command to find ME values
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));     //sends the buffer to the socket 
    read(sock, buf, 80);               //read from socket to get results.    
        sscanf(buf, "S MELR %i %i\n", &lme, &rme);       
    lme=100+(100-lme) ; rem=100+(100-rme);  // compensate  ????
}
```

Comment: @Muhibur Rahim : I´m curios... Did you test this??